# Prometheus keeps showing up on 9090 even if docker container not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus

Following a tutorial. I have the following docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:ro

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./backup:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgrespassword
      POSTGRES_DB: shop

  postgres-exporter:
    image: prometheuscommunity/postgres-exporter
    ports:
      - 9187:9187
    environment:
      DATA_SOURCE_NAME: "postgresql://postgres:postgrespassword@postgres:5432/shop?sslmode=disable"
    links:
      - postgres
      - prometheus
```

And this as my prometheus.yml:

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: prometheus
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["localhost:9090"]
  - job_name: postgres-exporter
    static_configs:
      - targets: ["postgres-exporter:9187"]
```

I realized I needed to make some changes, so brought down the containers. But noticed I could still access:

http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9090/config

In checking the containers, it seemed to restart Prometheus. I disabled it again, checked on the browser, and saw it got restarted again. Additionally, any changes I make to prometheus.yml aren't reflected in the config.

I checked running services, there is no instance of prometheus running outside of docker.
Disabling the docker service brings it down, but as soon as I re-enable it, it appears again, always with the old config.

any ideas? (have tried killing the port as well, just respawns)

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                    COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS      NAMES
34c66a78b75e   prom/prometheus:latest   "/bin/prometheus --c…"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours   9090/tcp   my-prometheus.1.iht6uk1okzlb3gc9y9jdaf2fg
```

Comment: Show what docker ps and docker-compose ps returns, a prometheus container is still running, you should find it there.

Comment: @Ludwig There is one running, but I have no idea why.  It starts whenever I access   http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:9090/config. I can close the container, but it will always restart when accessed via http

Comment: Use the docker rm command, the container has always been up, look at the container status.
Is there some things you've omitted about your setup ? I'm a bit suspicious about that container name "my-prometheus.1.iht6uk1okzlb3gc9y9jdaf2fg", also give a link to your tutorial.

Comment: I'm using the following tutorial: https://dev.to/nelsoncode/how-to-monitor-posgresql-with-prometheus-and-grafana-docker-24c8

Removing the container works, but if I access that URL a container by the same name is immediately started. If I wanted to just completely get rid of promehteus from showing up via http, I honestly wouldn't know how. Only way I've been able to prevent it from appearing has been turning off docker completely.

And any changes to my `prometheus.yml` file are not reflected on the new running container. It's always showing the old config.

Comment: And as you mentioned, I have no idea where the name `my-prometheus.1` is coming from.

Comment: Check your docker server/docker-compose version (due to the weird container name suffix) and tell your exact versions.
There is no wake-on-lan in docker, the container is still running, show what docker ps -a; docker rm -f #the container name#; docker ps -a returns, I can't guess anything here.

Comment: In the end, I had a separate service running which was recreating the container anytime my host was accessed on that port. Was overriding the one I was generating via docker compose. Deleting that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the exact same issue, turns out docker swarm was causing the issue.

To verify, run `docker inspect container_name` command and check if it mentions docker swarm.

If it does, use `docker service ls` to list the service and remove that particular service which is creating the my-prometheus-1.xyz containers using `docker service rm service_name`.

This solved the issue for us.